# Doctrine ORM Annotations not read - SimpleAnnotationsReader

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I want to be able to use my database just like described in this tutorial:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html

Unfortunately, the annotations that were generated through the command

```
$ php app/console doctrine:generate:entity
```

are not read as annotations.

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update -f
```

returns

```
No Metadata Classes to process.
```

The file looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace ResBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Page
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Page
{
... class here with @ORM\ annotations
```

I think I have found out that this might be because doctrine uses the *SimpleAnnotationsReader* which only parses annotations like *@Column* and not *@ORM\Column*.

The ORM part of my *config.yml*

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    entity_managers:
        default:
            auto_mapping: true
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
            mappings:
                ResBundle:
                    type: annotation
                    is_bundle: false
                    dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../src/ResBundle/Entity/
                    prefix: Resbundle\Entity
                    alias: ResBundle
```

The problem is that I have no clue how to switch to the normal AnnotationsReader, answers to other similar questions could not enlighten me.

Is there a setting in my *config.yml* that need to change? What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check that your bundle is activated.

Second, if you're using bundles, there should be no reason for all that complicated stuff in your config. Why don't you just use [the default Doctrine ORM configuration](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.8/app/config/config.yml#L56-L59)?

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
```

That should do the job, given your bundle is properly registered and activated.

Comment: I used *php app/console generate:bundle* to create the bundle... is there any possibility that this did not set up the bundle correctly? Reducing the orm configs did not help for now. Thank you for helping!

Comment: php app/console config:dump-reference outputs my bundle (amongst other o.c.), so I think everything is fine with it?

Comment: Well, there are many ways your application could be broken. Try a fresh Symfony project and see if it works there.

Comment: Yeah well.. that was it. Whatever broke my app, I don't know, but a 'virgin' app works well with this config setup. Thanks!